# Can I use JS to use one string at a time from JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am making a trivia game to better understand working with JSON files. Currently, I am using JS and jQuery to extract strings of questions and answers that will make up the trivia game, like so:

```
$.getJSON('/trivia.json', function(data) {
var items = [] 
$.each(data, function (item, i) {
items.push('<p style="font-weight: bold" id="">' + ' Question ' + i.order + '    - ' + i.question + '</p>');
items.push('<input type="checkbox" id="">' + ' A1: ' + i.answer1 + '</p>');
items.push('<input type="checkbox" id="">' + ' A2: ' + i.answer2 + '</p>');
items.push('<input type="checkbox" id="">' + ' A3: ' + i.answer3 + '</p>');
items.push('<input type="checkbox" id="">' + ' A4: ' + i.answer4 + '</p>');
items.push('<input type="checkbox" id="">' + ' Correct Answer: ' + ' - ' +   i.correcta + '</p>');});
```

And then it appends this quiz's question/answer options to a div:

```
$('<p/>', {
'class': 'my-new-list2',
html: items.join('')
}).appendTo('#example2');});
```

The good news is that the array is coming through; however, it is displaying the entire list of questions and answers at the same time (so the user sees seven sets of questions/answers right now).

I want the user to ultimately only see one question before they submit an answer, and then for the quiz to cycle to the next question.

Therefore, I am wondering if:

1. More simply, I can use items.push to call only the first string in the array so it loads only the first question/answer combo from the array, which would solve some of the issue, and;
2. If so, could I use a submit button to load the second question/answer string and let the user go through the questions?

Comment: Why not making a seperate array for questions and answers?

Comment: I might be missing the point, but even when they are in the same array as they are now, the items.push lines are calling individually items with the Question label and then the Answers labeled Answer1, Answer 2, and so on. If I generated two separate arrays for Questions and Answers and then ran a similar function, wouldn't it still display the entire array of Questions and the entire array of Answers? My concern is that I only want to show one question + 4 answers at a time, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Ok I see where your getting at. You could hide the answer with css and when the user hits submit or show answer you can show the user the answer with simple jquery. For your other question, you could show the first question doeing something like this `items[0]`. Next question -> make ajax call and make `items[1]`

Comment: How many `question`s are returned at `data` ? Tried _"2. If so, could I use a submit button to load the second question/answer string and let the user go through the questions?"_ ?

Comment: @Mikey - That makes sense to me. Call the first item in the array and then cycle through them. I tried it by changing var items = [] to var items = [0] but it wasn't able to load the data. Can you clarify where I should be specifying that item? Also, since it looks like this is the ideal method, if you want to reply as an answer so I can accept it, that would be great (in case anyone has a similar issue down the road). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplification of your problem and not server side but this is basically what you can try: http://jsfiddle.net/p8ed51eo/1/

```
var number= 0;

(function () {
    var q = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    var display = q[number];
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = display;
    number++;
})()//self invoking function for first run of script

document.getElementById('next').onclick=function () {
    var q = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    var display = q[number];
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = display;
    number++;
}//function to jump to next item in array
```